# How to access class member from function in method class in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this typescript code:

```
    module MyPage {

    export class MyVm {

        ToDo : string;

        Load() {
            //can access todo here by using this:
            this.ToDo = "test";

            $.get("GetUrl", function (servertodos) {
                //but how do I get to Todo here??
                this.ToDo(servertodos); //WRONG ToDo..
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The question is, how do I access the todo member field in the $.get callback?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

TypeScript also supports arrow function that preserve lexical scoping. Arrow functions result in similar code to Jakub's example but are neater as you don't need to create the variable and adjust usage yourself:

Here is the example using an arrow function:

```
$.get("GetUrl", (todos) => {
    this.ToDo(todos);
});
```

Comment: This is one of my favourite things about Typescript.

Comment: This could be much more clear if `data` was used in this example too

Comment: @SerjSagan in the original question, the `data` parameter was named `todos` as this is the kind of data that is being supplied by the call. You can use `data` in place of `todos` in the above example if you wish. The `todos` parameter would contain the data object that jQuery passes to the callback.

Comment: @Sohnee 'this' does not work for me as shown above. Please refer to the question link and correct me if I am doing something wrong.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362178/this-scope-in-typescript-callback-function

Answer (score 13):

The same way you do it in javascript

```
export class MyVm {
    ToDo : string;

    Load() {
        //can access todo here by using this:
        this.ToDo = "test";
        var me = this;

        $.get("GetUrl", function (todos) {
            //but how do I get to Todo here??
            me.ToDo(todos); //WRONG ToDo..
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Aha.. my lack of javascript skills

Comment: While this is technically correct, using arrow functions is the better way to do this.

Comment: This techinque works for other similar scenarios. Was a pointer in the right direction for me.

Answer (score 1):

Fenton is right.

But you can also do this:

```
 mycallback(todos, self) { self.todo(todos)); }
 $.get('url', mycallback(todos, this));
```